# Rails app with basic symmetric encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, encryption, heroku

I'm a fairly new developer and I've encountered my first project where it will be important to be able to store certain fields encrypted within the database.

I'm on the most current version of Ruby/Rails, hosted on Heroku and using Git for source control. I installed the symmetric-encryption gem and SORT of have it working. But, when it comes to security, I know "sort of" doesn't cut it.

So, I set up the env variable with a key inside Heroku and have created a column in my database called `:encrypted_access_code`. When I submit a form, passing an `:access_code` parameter, it stores an encrypted version inside the `:encrypted_access_code` column. If I call the `.decrypt` method on that string, the method properly decrypts it and returns the original value. That seems, by what I can tell, to all be working correctly.

The problem is that I am still able to call `MyModel.access`_code, both in console and in the view, and it returns the unencrypted value. That column is no longer present in my database but it's still letting me call it - not good and I'm not sure where I went wrong. I'm sure it has something to do with symmetric-encryption and my not understanding it fully, but I haven't been able to find a truly comprehensive guide on getting it up and running. Using the creator's site I used his example to add the bits I needed in my model but I must be missing something. Any help would be super, super appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Step 1 in any project like this is to read [the book](https://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html) on encryption. Step 2 is to start coding. What are you trying to create here? An encrypted database field only the customer can access, such as when they and only they have the private key necessary to unlock it, or one that's simply "encrypted" with a key stored on the server anyway making all this fuss rather pointless? Unless the key to unlock this information is stored somewhere far, far away from the database, this is no better than simply securing your database.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply and the link to the book - I'll check that out. These are all good questions and illuminate exactly how green I am when it comes to this portion of a project. To help clarify, the application is only going to be used internally, by employees, and they should be able to view the :access_code if needed. For security's sake, though, I thought it would be prudent to have them stored encrypted to provide an additional layer of security. Also, the key is stored in an ENV variable in Heroku. Is your point that Heroku is secure enough as it is to not worry about this?

Comment: Encrypting the field to prevent unauthorized access, and then throwing the key into the application environment used by everyone is kind of self-defeating. The only limit to the password at that point is application logic, in which case encryption is a non-factor. It's usually not useful to encrypt fields within the database. Something like encrypting backups of the database that cannot be decrypted without a private key not present on the server is not a bad idea, such as using GPG.

Comment: That actually makes a bucket-load of sense. So, since it is information that should be available to any logged-in users, I should just not even bother with storing it encrypted and trust Heroku to not become compromised. Encryption is primarily for storing data that limited people, or even no one, should ever be able to see, but the application still needs to be able to use? Like users' passwords? And thanks again for the responses and clarification you've provided - I'll definitely be paying it forward!

Comment: Generally if you're employing encryption within an application it's to prevent the application from seeing the data. That is the user holds the keys, you're just storing it. If you wanted particular people to see particular passwords you'd encrypt those passwords with their public key so only the holder of the private key could decode it, or like PGP, you'd encode the one-time key for each password for each recipient. A lot of this is covered in Schneier's book. What use is a locked door if you have the key stuck in it, right? It's only when keys are held privately you actually have security.